# Accentuation in pages are behaving differently

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, diacritics

I have the following view:

```
@model MyModel1
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Breadcrumb = "Gerenciar Acessos - Índices";
}
```

The second one:

```
@model MyModel2 
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Pesquisar";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Breadcrumb = "Visualizar Bilhetes de Ligação";
}
```

In the first one breadcrumb the output html is: Gerenciar Acessos - Índices.

In the second one breadcrumb the output html is: Visualizar Bilhetes de LigaÃ§Ã£o

Why? Oo

OBS: I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3.

--EDIT

```
<div id="breadcrumb">
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Breadcrumb)
</div>
```

Comment: Can you include the code where you render the breadcrumb?

Comment: I edit the question with the code.

Comment: Did you make sure both views use the same encoding? (Preferably UTF-8) The BOM might also be relevant.

Comment: UTF-8 causes the bad accents... i change to Unicode 1200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, i change the Save Options of the file:

- Open the problematic file in Visual Studio.
- On the File menu click “Advanced Save Options“
- From “Encoding” combo select "Unicode - Codepage 1200"
- Click OK.
- Save the file (Ctrl + S) ^^

Answer (score 1):

It must have to do with the encoding of these strings. See if the second file might be saved as UTF-8 but the first file not. I'm not too familiar with ASP.NET; in Ruby another problem source might be if you're missing the "# encoding: UTF-8" tag at the top of the code. Or of course if you're editing one of the strings later with a string function that doesn't support Unicode.